# How to fully wait browser load after a form submission by EvaluateScriptAsync in CefSharp.OffScreen

Tags: .net, .net-core, cefsharp, .net-7.0, cefsharp.offscreen

I am using the below method to submit a form:

```
  var _Command = "document.querySelector(\"body > x > y > z\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"d > form > ep-button\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"button\").click()"
  JavascriptResponse scriptResult = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(_Command);
```

However this doesn't wait browser to fully load after command execution. How can I do that?

The command works I have tested

I am using .NET 7 and CefSharp.OffScreen

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WaitForNavigationAsync](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/107.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_OffScreen_ChromiumWebBrowser_WaitForNavigationAsync.htm) for this purpose.

```cs
var navigationTask = browser.WaitForNavigationAsync();
var evaluateTask = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync($"window.location.href = '{url}';");

await Task.WhenAll(navigationTask, evaluateTask);

var navigationResponse = navigationTask.Result;
var executeResponse = evaluateTask.Result;
```

[WaitForNavigationAsyncTests xUnit Tests](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Test/Navigation/WaitForNavigationAsyncTests.cs) for reference.